# Implementing C# Network Sniffer in Linux

Tags: c#, network-programming

So i've been banging my head against the wall with that for quite a while now. I wrote a Program that captures IP-Packages that are delivered to a computer and gives them out to the command line. I wrote it in C# using sockets. The code is down below. On Windows, the code works fine. My task however is to run that code on a Linux-Based platform. The first Problem is that the Protocol (ProtocolType.IP) seems to be not supported. Also, when configuring the IOControl, i use a command that is windows specific. Why is the protocol not supported and are there any alternatives to the commands i used to make the code work on Linux?
Apologies for any bad writing or grammar since i am not a native speaker.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;

namespace Watchdog.IPListener
{
class IPListener
{
static Socket socket;
static byte[] In = new byte[4] { 1, 0, 0, 0 };
static byte[] Out = new byte[4];
static byte[] Buffer = new byte[24576];
static int PackagesReceived = 0;
static string logmsg = null;

        static public void StartCapturing(string ipaddress)
        {
            try
            {
                socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.IP);
                socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipaddress), 0));
                socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AcceptConnection, true);
                socket.IOControl(IOControlCode.ReceiveAll, In, Out);
                StartReceiving();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex);
            }
        }
    
    
        public static void StartReceiving()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                int bytesReceived = socket.Receive(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
                if (bytesReceived > 0)
                {
                    PackagesReceived++;
                    ConvertReceivedData(Buffer, bytesReceived);
                }
                Array.Clear(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
            }
        }
```

I tried running the code that works on Windows on Linux but i get the Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (93): Protocol not supported

Comment: What is the actual goal? What do you mean by "network sniffer"? I would have expected it to mean something like wireshark, but that needs to capture packets before they have been thru the OS network stack, using something line nCap/LibCap.

Comment: I'm trying to view incoming and outgoing IP Datagrams (they are later converted into the underlying protocols like TCP and UDP) on a linux based system.

Comment: If you intend to view packets from any other application you will need to reconsider your method. Using sockets in this way will only allow you to view data that is sent/received by *your* application.

Comment: No, im trying to capture the packets coming in from the network like wireshark and want to implement that into a linux based system. As i already said, i have it working on windows already but in linux some of the code isnt recognized.